# How to upload an image from Play webpage and store it in MongoDB without GridFS?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I have a simple website where I can upload articles and show them to site visitors. Articles are stored in MongoDB.
I decided to add a simple feature which will allow admin to insert an image to the top of the article. And I wanted this image to be stored in MongoDB within the same article document.
What is a simplest way to achieve this without need to use GridFS?

Comment: It is not quite practical. Serving static content shouldn't be so expensive.

Comment: As already mentioned in a lot of articles - it suits a lot of cases and comes with benefits the MongoDB already gives you.
Also response with image data can be cached if needed, that's not hard.

Comment: Fair enough, glad you helped yourself.

Comment: For me there were two main benefits:

1)No need to store images in file system - so I did not need to implement more code for this. Also quite questionable if serving from the FS will be really much faster than serving that way with response caching.
2) If I need to migrate to other instance - I just dump the mongoDB, roll the dump on the other instance and I'm done.

Comment: My bad, didn't word my concerns properly in the first place. I was referring to memory usage.  It is a treasure for mongodb, and wasting it to what can be served as a binary stream feels a bit posh, but yeah, if it works for you it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, so the solution is outlined for all people who will need the same stuff. It has of course its limitations, like the maximal image size of 16Mb, but for a lot of cases it is not relevant.

Relevant part of my DAO:

```
trait DocumentService {
  ....
  def updatePicture(data:Array[Byte], title:String)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext):Future[UpdateResult]
  def picture(title:String)(implicit ec:ExecutionContext):Future[Option[Array[Byte]]]
}
```

Here `title` is a title of the article which is unique and serves as a key in articles extraction and all related operations for a particular article.

Implementation:

```
package services

import javax.inject.Singleton

import com.mongodb.client.result.UpdateResult
import model.Annotation
import org.bson.types.Binary
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoClient}
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._
import org.mongodb.scala.model.Updates._
import _root_.scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

/**
  * Created by Alex on 7/13/2016.
  */
@Singleton
class MongoDocumentService extends DocumentService{
  val mongoClient:MongoClient = MongoClient()
  val db = mongoClient.getDatabase("test")
  .....
  override def updatePicture(data: Array[Byte], title:String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[UpdateResult] = {
    val collection = db.getCollection("items")
    val update = set("picture.data", new Binary(data))
    collection.updateOne(equal("title", title), update).toFuture().map(sx => sx.head)
  }

  override def picture(title: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[Array[Byte]]] = {
    val collection = db.getCollection("items")
    collection.find(equal("title", title)).first()
      .toFuture()
      .recoverWith{case e:Throwable => {println(e); Future.failed(e)}}
      .map{seq => if(seq.isEmpty) None else seq.head.get("picture").map(p => p.asDocument().get("data")).map(r => r.asBinary().getData)}
  }
}
```

The `updatePicture` method inserts the picture data to a particular article document. As input it gets array of bytes and uses the `Binary` type to encode them.

The `picture` methods retrieves the picture raw bytes from the article document.

Now related controller methods for the picture file uploading and retrieval of picture for the `<img src="...">` tags:

```
def updatePicture = AdminAction.async(parse.multipartFormData){implicit request =>
    request.body.file("contentField").fold(Future.successful(Redirect(routes.MainController.index())))
    {filePart =>
      val tempFile = new File("./temp.txt");
      filePart.ref.moveTo(tempFile, true)
      val in = new FileInputStream(environment.getFile("./temp.txt"))
      val content = Stream.continually(in.read()).takeWhile(_ != -1).map(_.toByte).toArray
      val formOtherFields = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded
      val title = formOtherFields("titleField").head
      documentService.updatePicture(content, title).map(
        r => {
          in.close()
          tempFile.delete()
          Redirect(routes.MainController.index())
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

This controller action handles the image file upload, it uses multipart form data parser to access the file data and feed it then to the relevant DAO method shown above.

```
def picture(title:String) = Action.async{implicit request =>
    documentService.picture(title).map{
      case r => Ok(r.getOrElse(Array.empty[Byte]))
    }
  }
```

This method is used to render image on the article's view as the `<img src="...">` tag like here:
`<img src="/picture/@{document.get("title").get.asString().getValue}"/>`

Relevant part of the `routes` file:

```
POST    /updatePicture              controllers.MainController.updatePicture
GET     /picture/:title             controllers.MainController.picture(title:String)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a base 64 encoding of the image and add it to the document. Just beware that the maximum MongoDB BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

Comment: Yes, I have outlined this solution below in the answer. Not sure if `Binary` MongoDB type uses base64 encoding, but probably it does.